# Sum of columns matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I found this exercise:

> Let $A\sim\begin{bmatrix}1&3&6&1\\0&0&1&3\\0&0&-5&3\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$ where the equivalence was accomplished solely through row transformations. Find all solutions of $AX=B$ if $B$ is the sum of the first, second and fourth column of the $A$ matrix.

I don't know how to interpret this. More specifically, I have no idea what $B$ is supposed to be. My first thought was that $B$ is a 1x3 matrix but as such it cannot be the result of multiplication involving 4x4 matrix. What is $B$ in this exercise?

Comment: B is a 4x1 matrix (or 4 vector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naively, I would say that
$$ B = \left( \begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\0 \end{array} \right) + 
\left( \begin{array}{c} 3 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\0 \end{array} \right) + 
\left( \begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 3 \\ 3 \\0 \end{array} \right) = 
\left( \begin{array}{c} 5 \\ 3 \\ 3 \\0 \end{array} \right).$$

Comment: I will accept this as a valid logic, but would like to note that the exact values may be wrong due to not knowing $A$ matrix, we only know matrix acquired from $A$ by performing row transformations.

Comment: Ok then I understand more precisely where is the difficulty. However, the answer to your question about $B$ remains the same: it is a $4 \times 1$ matrix since $A$ stays a $4 \times 4$ matrix even after row transformations. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. It makes logical sense for that to be $B$.

Comment: Ok then. Since $A$ is obtain by elementary row manipulations of the matrix you gave - let us denote it $A_0$ - we can write $A = P A_0$ (see for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix): _Left multiplication (pre-multiplication) by an elementary matrix represents elementary row operations, while right multiplication (post-multiplication) represents elementary column operations_).

Comment: Then, if you denote $B_0$ the matrix given by the sum of the first, second and fourth colum of $A_0$, you can show that $B=PB_0$. Hence, you have to solve $PA_0X=B_0$, which is simply $A_0X=B_0$.